# regex needed which matches for two sample string

Tags: java, regex

I have two input strings :

`this-is-a-sample-string-%7b3DES%7dFPvKTjGHUA3lD9Us70rfjQ==?Id=113690_2&Index=0&Referrer=IC`

`this-is-a-sample-string-%7b3DES%7dFPvKTjGHUA3lD9Us70rfjQ==`

What I want is only the `%7b3DES%7dFPvKTjGHUA3lD9Us70rfjQ==` from both of the sample strings.

I tried by using the regex `[a-zA-Z-]+-(.*)` which works fine for the second input string.

```
String inputString = "this-is-a-sample-string-%7b3DES%7dFPvKTjGHUA3lD9Us70rfjQ==";
String regexString = "[a-zA-Z-]+-(.*)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("--->" + matcher.group(1) + "<---");
} else {
    System.out.println("nope");
}
```

Comment: Does it always end with `==`, i.e. is it always a Base64 string?

Comment: Regex matches patterns. What is the pattern here? Text between the last hyphen and last `=` inclusive?

Comment: this-is-a-sample-string-%7b3DES%7dFPvKTjGHUA3lD9Us70rfjQ==?Id=113690_2&Index=0&Referrer=IC  
It does not always end with == but if there is ? in the string, the question mark and all other characters after the ? should not be considered. If the ? is not present then all the characters after the last - should be taken. your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following patterns match the desired group with the limited information and examples provided:

```
-([^-?]*)(?:\?|$)

.*-(.*?)(?:\?|$)
```

The first will match a hyphen then group all the characters up to either the ? or the end of the string.

The second matches as many characters and hyphens as possible followed by the smallest string to either the next question mark or the end of the string.

There are dozens of ways of writing something that will match this text though so I'm kinda just guessing if this is what you wanted. If this is not what you're after please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.